# Skew coordinate system transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I am currently working through problems in Susan Lea's *Mathematics for Physicists*. However I am stuck on a problem and the book is not known to errata. The problem is:

11. A Skew (non orthogonal) coordinate system in a plane has x'-axis along the x-axis and y'-axis at an angle $\theta$ to the x axis, where $\theta$ < $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

    (a) Write the transformation matrix that transforms vector components from the Cartesian x-y system to the skew system.

The solution manual says [the new coordinates are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hs30.png)

$y' = \frac{y}{sin\theta}$

which I also obtain, but the result:

$x' = x-\frac{y}{tan\theta}$

I simply cannot understand why this is the result. There is no explanation for this and embarrassingly enough I have spent more than 2 hours on this. Can someone please explain this to me, or let me know if it is a mistake. Thank you!

Comment: You need to compute the coordinates of the Cartesian basis in terms of the skew basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by drawing a point at some arbitrary point in the plane. For simplicity, I would draw it between $x'$ and $y'$ axes in the first quadrant. Now draw some parallel lines to $x'$, $y'$ and $y$ axes from that point. The perpendicular from your point to the $x$ axis has length $y$, the parallel to the $y'$ axis has length $y'$. The angle between the parallel to $y'$ and $x$ is $\theta$, so in the triangle formed by the parralels to $y'$ and $y$ with the $x$ axis you get $$\sin\theta=\frac{y}{y'}$$ In the same triangle, $$\cos\theta=\frac{x-x'}{y'}$$
From the first equation then $$y'=\frac{y}{\sin\theta}$$
If you plug into the second equation you get $$x'=x-\frac{y\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

Comment: How did you figure out the numerator for the cosine equation? Why do you subtract there?

Comment: @Shocked Draw the picture. Say the arbitrary point is $P$, with coordinates $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$. When you draw the line perpendicular to $x$ you intersect the $x$ axis at $A=(x,0)$. Draw the parallel to $y'$ and you intersect the $x$ axis at $B=(x',0)$. Then the length of $AB$ is $x-x'$. $\triangle ABP$ is a right angle triangle with $\angle BAP=90^\circ$.

Answer (score 3):

Let the unit vectors in the skew system be $s_1, s_2$. Then the coordinates of $s_1,s_2$
in terms of the standard basis $e_1,e_2$ are $(1,0)^T, (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)^T$.

Let $S=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cos \theta \\ 0 & \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}$, then if $n=(n_1,n_2)^T$ are the coordinates of a point in the skew basis, this corresponds to a point $S n$ in the standard basis.

Hence to map back from the standard basis to the skew system we take the inverse.

We have $S^{-1} = {1 \over \sin \theta } \begin{bmatrix} \sin \theta & -\cos \theta\\ 0 &1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -{1 \over \tan \theta}\\ 0 & {1 \over \sin \theta} \end{bmatrix}$.

Hence a point whose coordinates are $(x,y)^T$ in the standard basis will correspond to
coordinates $(x-{y \over \tan \theta}, { y \over \sin \theta})^T$ in the skew system.

Comment: This is also a great answer, this helps much more from a linear algebra perspective as opposed to the geometric understanding I was originally going for. Very interesting, Thanks!